# UNION two ordered MySQL statements

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns (id, name, code) and 10 rows. Some of the rows don't have a code so that column is empty for some. **What I'm trying to accomplish is SELECT the rows with `code` column not empty first ordered by last inserted followed by all rows with `code` column empty ordered by last inserted.** 
I have tried

```
(SELECT * from tablename WHERE code <> '' ORDER BY ID DESC) UNION
(SELECT * from tablename WHERE code = '' ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

The UNION works but the order does not. I have read here about other questions and found out adding ORDER BY like I added will not work and I should add it at the end but that would not help me accomplish what I want and will mix rows that have a `code` with rows that don't.

Is there a way to succeed with what I'm looking for?

Comment: **Without code** means empty string (i.e., code <> '' is true) and not that the code column is null. right?

Comment: Yes, I'm not checking for null, I'm checking if empty. Sorry about that I didn't realize it will create confusion I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to put your sort logic in the `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT id, name, code
FROM tablename
ORDER BY code = '', ID desc;
```

Comment: @Raluca - Here is a contrived dataset in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31719e/2) for you to see

Comment: the question I posted is a simplified version so when I adapted I got error but I fixed it and now it seems your statement works. I've never seen this before could you explain in a few words how this works. Thanks

Comment: `code =''` is a Boolean expression that can be evaluated to 0 or 1. Since 0 sorts before 1 (in ascending order), I made what you wanted to  to be sorted first equate to false (It could have also been `ORDER BY  code <> '' DESC, ID desc`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT * from tablename WHERE code <> '' ORDER BY ID DESC) 
 UNION
(SELECT * from tablename WHERE code = '' ORDER BY ID DESC)
)tab ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT * from tablename ORDER BY code DESC,ID DESC
```

Change ASC/DESC as per you want it to show