# MYSQL UNION Sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, union

Can anyone give me some pointers to get this working??

I want to combine to queries into one listing with different sorting.
The first will be any business that are a spotlight sorted randomly, then all other listings sorted alphabetically.

This is what I'm using, but the sorting doesn't work.

```
(SELECT * FROM business_listings WHERE city='Toronto' AND spotlight='1' ORDER by rand())
UNION
(SELECT * FROM business_listings WHERE city='Toronto' AND spotlight='0' ORDER BY busname)
```

Comment: You need to apply an 'order by' clause to the result of the 'union'. It is explained at [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: See similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231060/union-two-ordered-mysql-statements/22231474#22231474

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using different order by with union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454815/using-different-order-by-with-union)

Comment: With a lot of businesses and only few with the spotlight flag it would be much more efficient to split this query into two and join listings in external language. Using union to join and mix them in mysql just to split them back with sophisticated order by rules looks really unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You may not need a `UNION`, use the `CASE` clause in `ORDER BY` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM business_listings 
WHERE city='Toronto'
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN spotlight='1' THEN FLOOR(RAND()*10) 
  WHEN spotlight='0' THEN 10 
END, busname
```

What it will do is, sort records using a random value (from 0 to 9) for records having spotlight=1. Whereas all records having spotlight=0 will come later because ORDER BY will use the value 10 as the sort order.

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bf6e/1

Answer (score 0):

from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454815/using-different-order-by-with-union)

**[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1319/10/0)**

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM business_listings
      WHERE city='Toronto'
      AND spotlight='1'
      ORDER by rand()) as t1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM business_listings
      WHERE city='Toronto'
      AND spotlight='0'
      ORDER BY busname) as t2
```